# Biblatex: Quotes in author names

Tags: biblatex

How can I put a nickname for an author in quotation marks (using biblatex)? The following example puts an erroneous period after "Doe":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Morgan,
  Title   = {Article title},
  Author  = {Hyde, Allan and Morgan, John {\enquote{Doe}} and Jekyll, Martin},
  Journal = {Journal title},
  Year    = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

And is there a smarter/more concise way to specify the quoted text in the bib file than `{\enquote{nickname}}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress this by using `biblatex`s `\nopunct` macro:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Morgan,
  Title   = {Article title},
  Author  = {Hyde, Allan and Morgan, John {\enquote{Doe}\nopunct} and Jekyll, Martin},
  Journal = {Journal title},
  Year    = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```